# Why session in Vim did not save buffer from other folder rather than ~?

Tags: vimrc, gvim, vim-windows

I use gVim on windows and save my current working files to session. However, when openning old session, it did not load files from other folder except home folder ~ (where I store my _vimrc file). My _vimrc setting is as below:

```
autocmd! VimLeave * mks! 
autocmd! VimEnter * if argc() == 0 | source ~/Session.vim | endif
```

File ~/test.txt was loaded but file C:\Users\VPG1HC\Desktop\project notes\test.txt was not loaded (it's empty). All the files are in current session. When I checked buffer, it's there but the content was empty. I opened with notepadd++ or reopened the file with Vim, then the content was loaded.

Comment: is that file in the session?

Comment: Don't you want to try vim-ctrlspace plugin?

Comment: Have you checked :buffers?

Comment: @eyalkarni not sure how ctrl-space is relevant here, can you explain?

Comment: OP, Welcome to [vi.se]! If you can [edit] to add more details, such as those asked of you in the comments, that will help get your question answered (I hope)!

Comment: vim-ctrlspace allows one to manage sessions. Probably wiser than to allow just one session (on load). I also recommend to change the setting on `shada` to save buffer list on exit. see `help 'shada'` (it is for neovim).

Comment: @eyalkarni this question is about (windows) gvim, and not neovim. So mentioning the `'shada'` option is just confusing.